# Promoting Headers from Rows to Columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am new to data analysis and I'm wondering if I can get pointers for what I am facing at the moment.

I have an ICS calendar that I am trying to export into a spreadsheet. However, the data I recieve is organised as follows:

| Data |
| --- |
| Event: NAME XXX |
| Date: xx xx xx |
| Location: NOWHERE |
| URL: [www.hi.com](http://www.hi.com) |
| Event: NAME YYY |
| Date: yy yy yy |
| Location: SOMEHWERE |
| URL: [www.hello.com](http://www.hello.com) |

... and so on

I need to be able promote the text before the : delimiter on every four rows as headers. so that my data looks like this:

| Event | Date | Location | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME X | xx xx xx | SOMEHWERE | hello.com |
| NAME Y | xx xx xx | NOWHERE | bye.com |

I can use SQL or Python or data visualisation software such as PowerBI, alternatively, good ol' Excel works fine.

I tried other tools  and workarounds such as uploading the ICS calendar into my Outlook calendar and then exporting the calendar. This worked fine but it is a work around.

I would like to be able to load the information via the ICS link directly into a CSV/Excel because I am using the information to populate a PowerBI Dashboard.

Comment: Are you sure that's an ICS calendar event?

Comment: the fields are named a bit differently. BEGIN, PRODID, DTSTART....etc just changed for simplification.

I basically need to do the following: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/cpwx69/converting_an_ics_file_with_powerquery/ 

but I was not able to follow the instructions.

Comment: I've never seen double pipes in an ics calendar file. Usually CRLF is used between fields so each field is a separate row. Regardless, PowerBI has an extract function that allows you to specify the delimiters to look between. Been a while so I'm not current on how it's done in the current version but you can specify ||DTSTART: as the first delimiter and the next field's identifier as the second delimiter.

Comment: Can you put some sample data?

Comment: Here is the document I working with [link] (shorturl.at/ektHK)

I basically need to get the following fields to be horizontal headers (BEGIN, DTSTART, DURATION, SUMMARY, UID, URL, ORGANIZER, LOCATION, DESCRIPTION, END)

Comment: @SamM thanks Sam. I am able to extract the headers but if you check the document I have uploaded here https://shorturl.at/ektHK, you will see that all the data is stored vertically. How can I transpose the dataset to give me the headers as horizontal and the rest of the data vertically.

Comment: [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter) and [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I need to group before I can pivot but I could not expand the tables after Grouping.

Comment: Why don't you share what you already got to help those who are trying to help you?

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, try this on your sample data set provided above:

```
  let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Column1] <> null),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1],"BEGIN:VEVENT") then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Custom] <> null)),
#"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Filtered Rows", {"Custom"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Errors","ORGANIZER;CN=","ORGANIZER/CN:",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({":"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Index"}),
removeHTML1 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.2",each try Text.Combine(List.Select(List.Alternate(Text.SplitAny(_,"<>"),1,1,1), each _<>""), "") otherwise null, type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(removeHTML1, List.Distinct(removeHTML1[Column1.1]), "Column1.1", "Column1.2"),
extractEmail = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "email", each List.Last(Text.Split([#"ORGANIZER/CN"],":")))
in  extractEmail
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride, this worked splendidly.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wci1LzSuxUvBz9HVViIiIUIrViVZySSxJtVKoqIAgsJBPfnJiSWZ+HlClf7iHa5ArWDQ0yMdKoby8XC8jUy85PxcshmxgZGQkkoGVlRCEZmCwv6+rRzimkak5OfkQU2MB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Data = _t]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
        Source, "Data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Data.1", "Data.2"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(
        #"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Added Index", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Data.1],"Event") then [Index] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(
        #"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(
        #"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
        #"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Data.1]), "Data.1", "Data.2"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(
        #"Pivoted Column",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

is how to get from here:

[image]

to there:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't work on the real data file including use of ORGANIZER;CN instead of ORGANIZER;CN:, blank rows that can't be pivoted, etc

Comment: @horseyride You're probably right about that, but I just wanted to answer the above question.